# How to implement listview item tap event in controller in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell  How to implement listview item tap event in controller in sencha touch

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:
If your list is like below:

```
{
  xtype: 'list',
  name: 'myList',
  store: 'test'
}
```

Then your controller will go like this:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        myList: 'list[name="myList"]'
    },
    control: {
        myList: {
            itemtap: 'onItemTap' // fires when listitem is tapped
        }
    }
},

onItemTap: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
    console.log('List Item was tapped of the list view');
    ........ your code goes here .........
}
```

Note: These small things you can find in sencha docs.